# Html and Javascript not getting the expected answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a new security assessment webpage in which I am using HTML and Java Script. For some reason, the code is not working properly and not getting the desired results. The way the page supposed to work is by having the user answer Yes or No questions, and when the user is done they can click submit. Then the page would display the number of questions answered yes, however when I click submit the only result I get is 0.

Any help would be appreciated it.

Thanks,

```js
<script>
    function calcscore() {
        var score = 0;
        $(".calc:checked").each(function() {
            score += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        });
        $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
    }
    $().ready(function() {
        $(".calc").change(function() {
            calcscore()

        });
    });


    window.sumInputs = function() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('calc'),
            result = document.getElementById('total'),
            sum = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            var ip = inputs[i];

            if (ip.class && ip.class.indexOf("total") < 0) {
                sum += parseInt(ip.value) || 0;
            }

        }

        result.value = sum;
    }
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <h1>Security Assessment </h1>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>PERSONNEL SECURITY</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1. Does your staff wear ID badges?

                <form>
                    Yes
                    <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" /> No
                    <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio1" value="0" /><br />

                </form>


            </td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2. Is a current picture part of the ID badge?


                <form>
                    Yes
                    <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio2" value="1" /> No
                    <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio2" value="0" /><br />

                </form>


            </td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3. Are authorized access levels and type (employee, contractor, visitor) identified on the Badge?

                <form>
                    Yes
                    <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio3" value="1" /> No
                    <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio3" value="0" /><br />

                </form>

            </td>

        </tr>


    </table>

    Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total" />


    <a href="javascript:sumInputs()"><input type="Submit" value="Submit"</a>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1) Wrap the whole thing in a `<form>` element, and remove the ones around the individual radio buttons 2) Don't put an `input` inside an `a`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `calc` is not a valid HTML tag name...

Comment: The HTML is invalid with at least 10 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix a few things in code. Don't wrap submit input inside an . Then if you want to select using class 'calc' you need to use '.calc'. Then you can call sumInputs() from onclick event of submit button.
To change value in text input you can use `$('#total').val(sum)`

```js
    function calcscore()
{
    var score = 0;
    $(".calc:checked").each(function()
{
        score+=parseInt($(this).val(),10);
}    );
    $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
}
 $().ready(function()
{
    $(".calc").change(function()
{
        calcscore()

}    );
}    );


   window.sumInputs = function() {
    var inputs = $('.calc:checked'),
        result = document.getElementById('total'),
        sum = 0;            

    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
    }
    
    $('#total').val(sum);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

  <h1>Security Assessment </h1>

 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>PERSONNEL SECURITY</th>
   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1. Does your staff wear ID badges? 

<form>
Yes
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" />
No
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio1" value="0" /><br />

</form> 


 </td>

   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2. Is a current picture part of the ID badge? 


<form>
Yes
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio2" value="1" />
No
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio2" value="0" /><br />

</form> 


</td>
    
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3. Are authorized access levels and type (employee, contractor, visitor) identified
on the Badge?

<form>
 Yes
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio3" value="1" />
No
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio3" value="0" /><br />

</form> 

</td>
      
  </tr>
 
 
</table>

Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>


<input type="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="sumInputs()">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you changed or what was wrong?\[edit\] Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Dij Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. I have another question, and I am hoping you could help me with it. If I want the result of the assessment to be sent to an email address when the user click submit. How would I do that ?

Comment: @apa1 SO is not the place for ongoing questions. If you have another question, create another question topic.